# How to instantiate com.android.server.ViewServer

Tags: android, reflection

In Android OS, I use reflection to get the `IWindowManager` :

```
Class tempClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
Method method = tempClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
IBinder binder = (IBinder) method.invoke(null,new Object[] { "window" });
IWindowManager mIWM = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(binder);
```

And use reflection get the `ViewServer` :

```
Class mViewServer = Class.forName("com.android.server.ViewServer");
```

But using follow code will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Constructor ct = mViewServer.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.forName("com.android.server.WindowManagerService"));
ct.setAccessible(true);
Object mVSObject = ct.newInstance(mIWM);
```

The `ViewServer` constructor is :

```
ViewServer(WindowManagerService windowManager) {
    ...
}
```

Who can help me, Thank you very much!

Comment: I suspect one problem is that you're assuming that your `IWindowManager` is a `WindowManagerService`. If you look at it in your debugger or just output its `getClass()`, I think you'll find it's actually an `IWindowManager.Stub.Proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

I using android 4.0 source code, and `ViewServer` only have one Constructor:

```
ViewServer(WindowManagerService windowManager, int port) {
        mWindowManager = windowManager;
        mPort = port;
    }
```

but your code:

```
Constructor ct = mViewServer.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.forName("com.android.server.WindowManagerService"));
```

have no `NoSuchMethodException` throw, so may be have this `Constructor`,

you can try this: type convert and pass this argument

```
(WindowManagerService)mIWM
```

if also dont work, suggestion to print the `ViewServer` all `Constructors` using this method:

```
class.getDeclaredConstructors();
```

to ensure the `Constructors` with your argument has existed.

Comment: Hi, idiotiger, thank you very much! The ViewServer is Android source code, it has two constructor: One is 'com.android.server.ViewServer(com.android.server.WindowManagerService)', and the other is 'com.android.server.ViewServer(com.android.server.WindowManagerService, int)'.

Comment: I have tried : (WindowManagerService)mIWM , but WindowManagerService is Android source code, so I don't know how to cast mIWM. You know, mIWM is in other process , it is a instance of WindowManagerService.

Comment: Hi @Peter Lawrey, Do you have any idea?Thanks.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, **bold** Do you have any idea?Thanks

Comment: @VonC, _**Do you have any idea?Thanks**_

Comment: Hi , **@linker**, Do you have any idea? 'Thanks!'

Comment: HI, @amit, **Do you have any idea?** `Thanks!`

Comment: so, the question is back to your require: why you want to init `com.android.server.ViewServer`, the system inner class, what you want to use this to do ?

Comment: In WindowManagerService, there is a function which name is startViewServer, when `ro.secure = 0` **and** `ro.debuggable = 1` , it will work very well! That mean `ViewServer` will be started.^_^

Answer (score 0):

to use a ViewServer ,you need to add the class ViewServer.java to your project and instantiate it in the onCreate , onResume and onDestroy , here is an exemple :

```
public class ViewServerActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ViewServer.get(this).setFocusedWindow(this);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);
}
```

}

here is an url to the class ViewServer.java [ViewServer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/wm/ViewServer.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Class<?> serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        Class[] cArg = new Class[1];
        cArg[0] = String.class;
        Method getServiceMethod = serviceManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getService", cArg);
        getServiceMethod.setAccessible(true);
        IBinder wmbinder =  (IBinder) getServiceMethod.invoke(null, Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```